# Fluid and responsive site calculations for css layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

If I am creating a responsive site most text gives an initial pixel size. I.e.:

```
Width = 940px
Target = 200px
target / Context = Result : 200 / 940 = etc etc
```

All is good.

The problem is that if I want a fluid site as well (increase of non vector based text size) I'm not sure how people are calculating from the initial width.

I'm working on the basis that I have reset the font size in the body to `1em` with the various other fixes in the HTML tag etc. I could guesstimate the a page width of `940px` is probably something like `60em` but this does seem rather fudgy.

Are there some other calculations or am I missing something here?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/). May be this is what you are looking for....

Answer (score 4):

Percentange can be used in these cases.

for example:
200/940 ~= 21%;

and use it as:

```
.a-class {
    width: 21%;
}
```

or you can refer to @media queries. You can define different width for different document sizes. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: This completely misses what I asked. I'll try and be clearer. Currently the page width is hard coded 940px wide. I want to make that width the equivalent in ems making it fluid. So how do I turn 940px or whatever into ....ems. As the equivalent I can still use 940 in my sub calculations.